# How to transform/flatten array of objects that contain arrays?

Tags: typescript

I have this data structure:

```json
{
"layers": [
    {
      "layer": "foo",
      "values": [
        {
          "timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "1970-01-01T01:00:00Z",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "1970-01-01T02:00:00Z",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "1970-01-01T03:00:00Z",
          "value": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "layer": "bar",
      "values": [
        {
          "timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "1970-01-01T01:00:00Z",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "1970-01-01T02:00:00Z",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "1970-01-01T03:00:00Z",
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to transform it to this:

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": 1
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "1970-01-01T01:00:00Z",
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": 1
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "1970-01-01T02:00:00Z",
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": 1
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "1970-01-01T03:00:00Z",
    "foo": 0,
    "bar": 1
  },

]
```

That is, each `timestamp` in the original data structure should have its own entry in the resulting array, and that entry should contain a key/value corresponding to the `layer`/`value` properties from the original structure.

How can I do this in TypeScript?

Comment: ```const results = new Array(data.layers[0].volumes.length * data.layers.length).fill(null).map(() => ({}));
data.layers.forEach((group, j) => {
  group.volumes.forEach((obj, i) => {
    console.log(obj)
    let a = { timestamp: obj.timestamp, group.layer: obj.volume }
    Object.assign(results[i], a)
  })
});```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLr1vw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This is exactly what I was lookin for, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach looks like this:

```
const dict: Record<string, Record<string, number>> = {}
for (const layer of data.layers) {
  for (const value of layer.values) {
    (dict[value.timestamp] ??= {})[layer.layer] = value.value;
  }
}
const flat = Object.entries(dict).map(([timestamp, v]) => ({ timestamp, ...v }));
```

This maintains a dictionary `dict` from `timestamp` keys to object values.  Dictionaries in TypeScript can be represented as plain objects with `string` [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) like `type Dictionary<V> = {[k: string]: V}`, or equivalently using the [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) like `type Dictionary<V> = Record<string, V>`.   The type of `dict` is `Record<string, Record<string, number>>`, meaning a dictionary of number-holding dictionaries.

The above code loops through each `layer` element of `data.layers` and each `value` element of `layer.values`.  Every timestamp in `value.timestamp` gets added as a key of `dict` if it doesn't exist (that's what `??={}` does, via [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)). Inside that object, a property is added with key `layer.layer` and value `value.value`.

(Note that you can do the above with purely functional methods like [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of state-mutating loops, but the current approach is simple and effective.)

Once that's done, we now have an object `dict` whose keys are `timestamp`s and whose values are your desired objects without the `timestamp` property.  We can fix that up by iterating through the its key-value pairs via [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) each value object into a new object with the appropriate `timestamp` property.

For your example this results in:

```
console.log(flat);
/* [{
  "timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "foo": 0,
  "bar": 1
}, {
  "timestamp": "1970-01-01T01:00:00Z",
  "foo": 0,
  "bar": 1
}, {
  "timestamp": "1970-01-01T02:00:00Z",
  "foo": 0,
  "bar": 1
}, {
  "timestamp": "1970-01-01T03:00:00Z",
  "foo": 0,
  "bar": 1
}]  */
```

which is what you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAsAKBjAIgBsEBPAUwCcICAuGAbV332zxf2LKrsIDMQIAgBpmHQgDcERAK7ka9Ju3GYxKzlACWAW3nJtAB14EAjAE4A7AAYAtFZN2TAFStXar91YBaIteoJSsuS8Vn4cAL6iyuJs6iwEWrrQCIbG5taOji4mnp4+UXGcgXIhYSyRZayV8Yl6KUb0ppa29llWAEy5rvnVRdIl9KHREQXqsYUJOnWpjektDvYuAMxd3r7D4gH9wYPV4WUAun4V0eMcXBSUxgBGCFej58XyvEpxZ-61yTOEc5mLHgC1g9-E9eCY9sCOO8VJMkvoGj9mn9nPZVj0No9tmCIdVoZtPvC0kjWv9OoD0YVJFj6OCMTATm9eoQCfUiRkSSiVuT1pStkFsXT9hsjtEhfgReEANy4XCgSCwOCaYBQegAJXIoEocAAPNBKJowABzYQwdWanV6g3GmBgGTaa5UAB8jrQmCFAkoMAAFHLoDASJcYCA+PAkAgAHQBqgQACUqnYHu9vtgTyDIajlHDT1j8Y4XsVyoYT3DLMMBxgAH4K+gMOEYwwM5HuJRy+hi09pewhULkzA+CRYOgAPLXABWGqg4fIYCg+vk+aVUBj4e0CAMXq9DFLBhNEgOcdQLq9GBg25N4YvEnpMZjnd9ICI5EjIENXv7SFvuAA9AAqRjjWFpgRJp2QWFE3G5UYCAEIRBig24rhpXBIlzZkpi+YDfg5bI0R5fhBBCeC7gFFCAO3Nl5jaMkIKBMRoIIuC6IQkiTTI9DCVmYkwOWXCoJgwimOIpCcHCcsYB-L8gA)

Comment: I'd `dict[value.timestamp] ??= {timestamp: value.timestamp}` and just `const flat = Object.values(dict);` saves the post processing of the entries.